# How to remote debug Tomcat (JPDA) when server has multiple virtual hosts running

Tags: debugging, tomcat, jpda

Im trying to remote debug Tomcat (JPDA) on a server that is running two virtual hosts using the same Tomcat container. How do I ensure the debugger connects to virtual host A and not B.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK - You cant do this.

JPDA operates at the JVM level, so if the underlying Tomcat for both hosts is the same, it's a single JVM.